# How to display records in week order

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, select, stored-procedures

I am having table containing record count 12000 and now i need to display as week basis as shown below

```
ID            Date                   count
1       4 week of November 2014       10
2       1 week of December 2014       120
3       2 week of December 2014       60
```

I tried as

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(150),datepart(day, datediff(day, 0, date)/7 * 7)/7 + 1) 
+ ' week of ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(150),datename(month,date)) 
+ ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(150),datepart(YEAR,date))
AS DisplayDate, 
COUNT(date) AS LettersCount
FROM tblV400_Leads_Letters 
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,date, GETDATE()) <= 28
GROUP BY date
```

And it gives out put as

```
 ID            Date                   count
 1    4 week of November 2014          10
 2    2 week of December 2014          74
 3    2 week of December 2014          78
 4    2 week of December 2014          59
 5    1 week of December 2014          79
 6    1 week of December 2014          68
 7    1 week of December 2014          60
 8    1 week of December 2014          68
 9    1 week of December 2014          83
```

Comment: It would still be useful to see your source data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are grouping by the `date` column, which means you will get one record output for each distinct value of `date`. Make sure that the expression in your `GROUP BY` clause, is exactly the same as what you are actually outputting:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(150),datepart(day, datediff(day, 0, date)/7 * 7)/7 + 1) 
+ ' week of ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(150),datename(month,date)) 
+ ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(150),datepart(YEAR,date))
AS DisplayDate, 
COUNT(date) AS LettersCount
FROM tblV400_Leads_Letters 
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,date, GETDATE()) <= 28
GROUP BY
    /* This is simply copied from the SELECT part of the query: */
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(150),datepart(day, datediff(day, 0, date)/7 * 7)/7 + 1) 
+ ' week of ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(150),datename(month,date)) 
+ ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(150),datepart(YEAR,date))
```

To avoid repeating code, you could wrap everything in a subselect:

```
SELECT DisplayDate, COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(150),datepart(day, datediff(day, 0, date)/7 * 7)/7 + 1) 
    + ' week of ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(150),datename(month,date)) 
    + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(150),datepart(YEAR,date)) AS DisplayDate
    FROM tblV400_Leads_Letters 
    WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,date, GETDATE()) <= 28
) T
GROUP BY DisplayDate
```

Also, I'm not completely sure what this code does: `CONVERT(VARCHAR(150),datepart(day, datediff(day, 0, date)/7 * 7)/7 + 1)`. But if you're trying to get the week number, an easier solution is simply to use `datepart(week, date)` or perhaps `datepart(iso_wk, date)` if you live in Europe.

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 different ways, both are assuming the week starts on monday.

If your weeks cut on monthchange so saturday 2012-09-01 and sunday 2012-09-02 is week 1 and monday 2012-09-03 is week 2 use this:

```
SELECT CAST(datediff(week, dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, date), 0)), 0), date - 1) + 1 AS VARCHAR(1))
+ ' week of ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(150),datename(month,date)) 
+ ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(150),datepart(YEAR,date))
AS DisplayDate, 
COUNT(date) AS LettersCount
FROM tblV400_Leads_Letters 
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,date, GETDATE()) <= 100
GROUP BY CAST(datediff(week, dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, date), 0)), 0), date - 1) + 1 AS VARCHAR(1))
    + ' week of ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(150),datename(month,date)) 
    + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(150),datepart(YEAR,date))
```

If you want weeks to be whole, so they belong to the month in which they start: So saturday 2012-09-01 and sunday 2012-09-02 is week 4 and monday 2012-09-03 is week 1 use this:

```
SELECT CAST(datepart(day, datediff(day, 0, date)/7 * 7)/7 + 1 AS VARCHAR(1))
+ ' week of ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(150),datename(month,date)) 
+ ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(150),datepart(YEAR,date))
AS DisplayDate, 
COUNT(date) AS LettersCount
FROM AECCFORECASTLOG 
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,date, GETDATE()) <= 100
GROUP BY CAST(datepart(day, datediff(day, 0, date)/7 * 7)/7 + 1 AS VARCHAR(1))
    + ' week of ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(150),datename(month,date)) 
    + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(150),datepart(YEAR,date))
```